# How to limit navigation menu (topnav.js) to only show one level deep?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Firstly, apologies, I'm coming at this from an angle of having no real idea what I'm doing.
We inherited a website which has topnav.js with its theme to give us top navigation.

When we add pages etc, these appears in the menu as expected. If we add a submenu/subpage to this, this acts as a drop down menu, great. But if we add another level to things this shows in the navigation menu as a flyout, which is by design I'd imagine. Is there a way to disable this? I only every want it to drop down and not go any further than 1 level deep.

For example:

- Policy

  - Key Policy Documents
  - Returns Policy
- Training

  - Key Training Documents
  - Senior Training
- Information Technology

  - PCs

    - Desktop **HIDE THIS**
    - Laptop **HIDE THIS**
- Printers
- Scanners

  - Type

    - Flatbed **HIDE THIS**
    - Handheld **HIDE THIS**

The pages will be there in the background, but I will link to them separately.

Here is the topnav.js which I think is doing all the work here:

```js
/**
 * findChildren
 * collect children of nav node and return
 * @param {*} id 
 */
function findChildren(id) {
    let childrenArr = [];
    Object.keys(SCS.structureMap).forEach(key => {
        if (SCS.structureMap[key].parentId === id) {
            childrenArr.push(SCS.structureMap[key]);
        }
    });
    
    return childrenArr;
}

/**
 * genNodeData
 * Generate href and name of node
 * @param {*} node
 */
function genNodeData(node) {
    let nodeName = node.name;
    let linkData = SCSRenderAPI.getPageLinkData(node.id) || {};
    let disabled = false;
    if (nodeName.endsWith("_DISABLED")) {
        disabled = true;
        nodeName = nodeName.substring(0, nodeName.indexOf("_DISABLED"));
    }
    let href = disabled ? `href="javascript:void(0);"` : `href="${linkData.href ? linkData.href : '#'}"`;
    return {
        href,
        nodeName
    };
}

/**
 * genNav
 * Generate nav DOM structure
 * @param {*} target
 */
function genNav(target) {
    let rootChildren = findChildren(SCS.navigationRoot);
    let rootChildrenOrder = SCS.structureMap[SCS.navigationRoot].children;
    let nav = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < rootChildrenOrder.length; i++) {
        let node = rootChildren.filter(node => {return node.id === rootChildrenOrder[i]})[0];
        let nodeData = genNodeData(node);
        if (!node.hideInNavigation) {
            if (node.children.length > 0) {
                nav += `<li class="nav-item dropdown px-2">
                    <a class="top-level-item nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ${nodeData.href}>${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        ${genSubNav(findChildren(node.id), node.children)}
                    </ul>
                </li>`;
            } else {
                nav += `<li class="nav-item px-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" ${nodeData.href}>${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
                </li>`;
            }
        }
    }

    $(target).html(nav);
}

/**
 * genSubNav
 * Generate second level nav list
 * @param {*} nodes
 * @param {*} nodeOrder
 */
function genSubNav(nodes, nodeOrder) {
    let secondLvl = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeOrder.length; i++) {
        let node = nodes.filter(node => {return node.id === nodeOrder[i]})[0];
        let nodeData = genNodeData(node);
        if (node.children.length > 0) {
            secondLvl += `<li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ${nodeData.href}>${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    ${genThirdNav(findChildren(node.id), node.children)}
                </ul>
            </li>
            `;
        } else {
            secondLvl += `<li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" ${nodeData.href}>${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
            </li>`;
        }
    };

    return secondLvl;
}

/**
 * genThirdNav
 * @param {*} nodes
 * @param {*} nodeOrder
 */
function genThirdNav(nodes, nodeOrder) {
    let thirdLvl = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeOrder.length; i++) {
        let node = nodes.filter(node => {return node.id === nodeOrder[i]})[0];
        let nodeData = genNodeData(node);
        thirdLvl += `<li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" ${nodeData.href}>${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
        </li>`;
    };

    return thirdLvl;
}

/**
 * genMobileNavModel
 * generates mobile nav structure
 * @param {*} target
 */
function genMobileNavModel(target) {
    let rootChildren = findChildren(SCS.navigationRoot);
    let rootChildrenOrder = SCS.structureMap[SCS.navigationRoot].children;
    let nav = `<li class="list-item-container nav-item">
        <a href="${(SCSRenderAPI.getPageLinkData(SCS.navigationRoot).href)}" class="link-text nav-link link-style">Home</a>
    </li>`;
    for (let i = 0; i < rootChildrenOrder.length; i++) {
        let node = rootChildren.filter(node => {return node.id === rootChildrenOrder[i]})[0];
        let nodeData = genNodeData(node);
        if (!node.hideInNavigation) {
            if (node.children.length > 0) {
                nav += `<li class="list-item-container nav-item dropdown">
                    <a ${nodeData.href} class="link-text nav-link link-style d-inline-flex">${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-toggle-icon d-inline-flex">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled ml-3 dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
                        ${genMobileSubNav(findChildren(node.id), node.children)}
                    </ul>
                </li>`;
            } else {
                nav += `<li class="list-item-container nav-item">
                    <a ${nodeData.href} class="link-text nav-link link-style">${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
                </li>`;
            }
        }
    }

    $(target).html(nav);
}

/**
 * genMobileSubNav
 * Generate second level nav list
 * @param {*} nodes
 * @param {*} nodeOrder
 */
function genMobileSubNav(nodes, nodeOrder) {
    let secondLvl = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeOrder.length; i++) {
        let node = nodes.filter(node => {return node.id === nodeOrder[i]})[0];
        let nodeData = genNodeData(node);
        if (node.children.length > 0) {
            secondLvl += `<li class="list-item-container nav-item dropdown">
                <a ${nodeData.href} class="link-text nav-link link-style d-inline-flex">${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
                <span class="dropdown-toggle-icon d-inline-flex">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </span>
                <ul class="list-unstyled ml-3 dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
                    ${genMobileThirdNav(findChildren(node.id), node.children)}
                </ul>
            </li>`;
        } else {
            secondLvl += `<li class="list-item-container nav-item">
                <a ${nodeData.href} class="link-text nav-link link-style">${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
            </li>`;
        }
    };

    return secondLvl;
}

/**
 * genMobileThirdNav
 * @param {*} nodes 
 * @param {*} nodeOrder 
 */
function genMobileThirdNav(nodes, nodeOrder) {
    let thirdLvl = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeOrder.length; i++) {
        let node = nodes.filter(node => {return node.id === nodeOrder[i]})[0];
        let nodeData = genNodeData(node);
        thirdLvl += `<li class="list-item-container nav-item">
            <a ${nodeData.href} class="link-text nav-link link-style">${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
        </li>`;
    };

    return thirdLvl;
}

/**
 * breadcrumb
 * generate breadcrumb trail
 * @param {*} id 
 * @param {*} active
 */
function breadcrumb(id, active) {
    let node = SCS.structureMap[id];
    let crumb = '';

    // Don't build breadcrumb if home is the active node
    if (node.id === SCS.navigationRoot && active) {
        crumb += `<li class="px-1 active">
            <span class="bc-home fa fa-home"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="px-1 active">Home</li>`;
        return crumb;
    }

    if ((typeof(node.parentId) !== 'undefined') && (node.parentId !== null)) {
        crumb += breadcrumb(node.parentId);
    }

    let nodeData = genNodeData(node);
    if (node.id === SCS.navigationRoot) {
        crumb += `<li class="px-1 active">
            <a ${nodeData.href}>
                <span class="bc-home fa fa-home"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <span class="px-1 small fa fa-angle-right"></span>`;
    }   else if (active) {
        crumb += `<li class="px-1 active">
            ${nodeData.nodeName === "View Event" ? "" : nodeData.nodeName}
        </li>`;
    } else {
        crumb += `<li class="px-1">
            <a ${nodeData.href}>${nodeData.nodeName}</a>
            <span class="pl-1 fa fa-angle-right"></span>
        </li>
        `;
    }

    return crumb;
}

function getPageId(name) {
    let siteMap = SCS.structureMap;
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(siteMap)) {
        if (value.name === name) {
            return value.id;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function getSearchResults(searchTerm) {
    let searchResultsPageId = getPageId("Search Results");
    if (searchResultsPageId) {
        // Store the search term, and redirect to search results page
        localStorage.setItem('OCMSearchTerm', searchTerm);
        let linkData = SCSRenderAPI.getPageLinkData(searchResultsPageId) || {};
        window.open(linkData.href, "_self");
    } else {
        console.error('The site must have a page named "Search Results"!');
    }
}

// Generate nav model and dom structures
document.addEventListener('scsrenderstart', function() {
    // Desktop
    genNav($('#navigation')[0]);
    // Allow navigation to dropdown items (not by default in Bootstrap)
    $(($) => {
        $('.nav-desktop .dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideDown(100);
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp(100);
        });
        $('.nav-desktop .dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
            location.href = this.href;
        });
    });
    // Apply href to home button
    $(".navbar-home").attr("href", SCSRenderAPI.getPageLinkData(SCS.navigationRoot).href);

    // Mobile
    genMobileNavModel($('#mobileNavDropdown .navbar-nav')[0], SCS.navigationRoot);
    $(($) => {
        $("#mobileNavDropdown .dropdown-toggle-icon").click(function() {
            $(this).siblings(".dropdown-list").slideToggle(250);
            $(this).toggleClass("down");
        });
    });
    // Apply the active page title to the mobile header
    if (SCS.navigationCurr !== SCS.navigationRoot) {
        $(".navbar-mobile").html(`<div class="active-page-name text-center">${SCS.structureMap[SCS.navigationCurr].name}</div>`);
    } else {
        $(".mobile-logo").removeClass("d-none");
    }

    console.log("[Get Navigation][Success]", SCS.structureMap);

    // Breadcrumb
    $('#breadcrumb').html(breadcrumb(SCS.navigationCurr, true));

    // Search
    $("#desktop-search-input").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
            let searchTerm = e.currentTarget.value;
            getSearchResults(searchTerm);
    }
    });
    $("#mobile-search-input").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
            let searchTerm = e.currentTarget.value;
            getSearchResults(searchTerm);
    }
    });
    $(".mobile-search-button").on('click', function () {
        let searchTerm = $("#mobile-search-input").val();
        getSearchResults(searchTerm);
    });
}, false);
```

This is where my knowledge leaves me, I don't really know how I can get that to do as I want it.
Is it the **node.children.length** I need to modify?

Comment: you could do in css for instance `ul > ul >ul > li { display: none}` but to be sure we need the html